# i have an error with the import androidx.cardview.R; how do i fix this

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio, flutter

I have come across this error androix.card.R; in flutter how do I fix this when the file states read only

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: the error is it cant find card view implements